# Notation to disambiguate substitution from multiplication of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, notation, soft-question

Substitution of an element of a $K$-algebra into a polynomial from $K[X]$ for $X$ is notationally indistinguishable from multiplication.  For example: if $P,Q\in K[X]$, is $P(Q - 1)$ the product of $P$ and $Q - 1$ or the result of the substitution of $Q - 1$ in $P$ for $X$?  (This ambiguity is particularly unwelcome in algebra textbooks and in other basic teaching material.)

The analogous problem of distinguishing function application from multiplication in "$f(g - 1)$" is less important because the domains of definition (or ["types"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory)) usually resolve the ambiguity.

I've thought of distinguishing substitution from grouping and multiplication by using different kind of parentheses.  For example: "$P(Q - 1)$" could mean the product of $P$ and $Q - 1$, while "$P[Q - 1]$" could mean the result of substitution of $Q - 1$ in $P$.  This would be not far from a rather common notation for substitution, for example, in [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) theory: $P[X\leftarrow (Q - 1)]$.

However, I am hesitating to adopt this convention.

Has any such or similar notation for disambiguating substitution from multiplication of polynomials been used in any respectable literature?

Comment: Use $X$ in the formulas: $P(X)(Q(X)-1)$ versus $P(Q(X)-1)$.

Comment: Wouldn't the context almost always make clear which is meant?

Comment: What is the context where you want to use these notations? A book? A thesis? Some papers? The best thing to do might be different. You can all the more adopt a specific notation as the work is large and specific to you. So (my 5 cents) it would be more acceptable in a thesis, then in a book (where you can have specific notations, but that's still painful for readers), then in papers (where introducing specific notations conflicts with papers having limited length, and readers limited time to skim them).

Comment: @lhf, this option is lengthy and introduces a new kind of objects: $P(X)$ is a polynomial in $X$, but what is $P$ then?

Comment: @MPW, "clear from context" is often ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $P \times Q$ or $P \cdot Q$ for the product and $P \circ Q$ for the composite.

Comment: I am not talking about composition, but about substitution. For example: $P(A - B)$, where $P\in K[X]$ is a polynomial and $A, B\in(K[X])^{n\times n}$ are square matrices.

Comment: @Alexey: ah, I didn't see that polynomials was only an example. Well, for polynomials substitution is composition. In general I agree that there's an ambiguity but you can resolve it by adopting different notation for multiplication and leaving substitution alone. I agree that this is a bit unsatisfying.

Comment: About "composition": since polynomials are not functions (but elements of an abstract free algebra), I hesitate introducing their "composition". For the same reason I would also find convenient to distinguish in notation the functional application from the polynomial substitution.

Comment: @Alexey: there is no issue with this. Polynomials are functions in the following sense: the ring $K[x]$ represents the forgetful functor from $K$-algebras to sets, and by the Yoneda lemma this means it can actually be identified as the monoid of endomorphisms of this forgetful functor. More explicitly, every polynomial in $K[x]$ defines a (set) endomorphism of every $K$-algebra given by substitution, this collection of endomorphisms is natural in the $K$-algebra, and conversely every such collection of natural endomorphisms is given by a polynomial.

Comment: The monoid operation here is composition, literally.